# Rails editing model from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Articles controller with corresponding Article Model.
I also have a different controller called Reviews.

They are not related or associated.

I am attempting to edit Article posts from reviews controller, but not able to do.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @article = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end


    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        raise params.inspect
        # @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        # if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
        #   # Handle a successful update.
        # else
        #   render 'edit'
        # end
    end

    private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :url,
                                   :tags, :news_date, :status)
    end

end
```

## reviews/edit.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

    <%= form_tag review_path(@article), method: "put" do %>
      <label>Article title:</label><br>
      <%= text_field_tag :title, @article.title %><br>

      <label>Article Description</label><br>
      <%= text_area_tag :body, @article.body %><br>

      <%= submit_tag "Submit Post" %>
    <% end %>   

  </div>
</div>
```

On submit action, why is it sending a `POST` request when I am specifically asking to set the form method to `PUT`?

[image]

## routes.rb

```
resources :reviews, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
scope module: 'api' do
    namespace :v1 do
        resources :articles, only: [:index, :show]
    end
end

>$ bundle exec rake routes
     Prefix Verb  URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
    reviews GET   /reviews(.:format)          reviews#index
edit_review GET   /reviews/:id/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
     review GET   /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#show
            PATCH /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
            PUT   /reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
v1_articles GET   /v1/articles(.:format)      api/v1/articles#index
 v1_article GET   /v1/articles/:id(.:format)  api/v1/articles#show
```

Comment: You should probably use form_for since you're using it on a certain object.

Comment: I tried that first, but then I get an `undefined method 'article_path'` for `form_for(@article)` in the edit.html.erb itself

Comment: Yes because the form_for would infer the url based on the object but you can then specify the url by doing:  form_for (@article, url: review_path(@article), method: 'put') do |f|

Comment: Okay. That is done. But the update action doesn't work. The error received is ditto same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you're trying to do here. In any case, what does your routing for the reviews controller look like? Why are you trying to subvert the normal Rails paradigms? This will lead to a lot of confusion.

Comment: This project is API only. I have added the reviews controller to monitor changes in the Article model.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: When you go to that url manually via a 'get' request do you actually have an article with id of 11?  It happened to me once where I deleted an object via the console and then hit the back button to the form which was still trying to update an old record I had just deleted which gave me this error.  Also, try doing method: :put instead of using string 'put'.

Comment: @arjun actually your code works (with the snippets you provided). Maybe check your logs when you hit submit to see what's happening. You can also check how your "html" form looks like in your browser dev tools.

Comment: Why can't you name your controller ArticlesController instead Review? If you want to access in URL by /reviews then you can easily do it in routes.rb.

Comment: @bkunzi01Yes the article exists. Strangely if the project is a full rails app, there is no issue. I am facing this problem with the API only mode.

Comment: @sovalina I had this same code in the full rails app. I am only facing this issue in the API only mode. Infact this is basic rails setup. I dont know why the API mode is behaving differently. I tried to inherit most of the Base class as much .

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag

":method - The method to use when submitting the form, usually either “get” or “post”. If “patch”, “put”, “delete”, or another verb is used, a hidden input with name _method is added to simulate the verb over post."

Comment: Well sorry not sure what you are trying to achieve then. But the answer to your question " why is it sending a POST request when I am specifically asking to set the form method to PUT" is in my answer. Now I am not sure you can force it to do it different. It says that it simulates the verb over post, i.e simulating your "put" over post, and the issue is something else, in your routing maybe?